# How many conjugacy classes of subgroups of order $p$ does $\operatorname{GL}_{3}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$ have?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

It is well known that any two subgroups of order $p$ in $\operatorname{GL}_{2}(
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ are conjugate. Then there is one possible
semidirect product of the form $$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{2}\rtimes
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$$ But this is not true for $\operatorname{GL}_{3}(
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

I want to know the number of isomorphism classes are for semidirect products of the form $$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{3}\rtimes
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$$

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: Consider the possible Jordan Normal Forms for an element of order $p$.

Comment: In fact there are two possible JNFs of elements of order $p$, so the answer to the question in the title is $2$. The answer to the question in the body of the post is $3$, because the direct product corresponds to an element of ${\rm GL}(3,p)$ of order $1$.

Comment: thank you very much [Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt).  Can you give the two isomorphism classes explicitly and the action associated to each class.